# Clear cache on application startup

Tags: angular, caching

I've been trying to clear the cache at the application startup for about two days without any success. I've red tons of posts and ideas but nothing is really working for me.

**That's the scenario**

In my `index.html` I've some scripts that get added, here's a simple snippet:

```
<script src="libraries/PuMAP_v1.7.6/EXT/tooltip/tooltip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libraries/PuMAP_v1.7.6/EXT/leaflet/v1.3.1/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="libraries/PuMAP_v1.7.6/EXT/leaflet.utfgrid/leaflet.utfgrid.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libraries/PuMAP_v1.7.6/EXT/leaflet.fullscreen/v1.0.2/leaflet.fullscreen.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libraries/PuMAP_v1.7.6/EXT/leaflet.omnivore/v0.3.1/leaflet.omnivore.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libraries/PuMAP_v1.7.6/EXT/leaflet.draw/v0.4.14/ext/GeometryUtil.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libraries/PuMAP_v1.7.6/EXT/leaflet.googlemutant/v0.7.0/Leaflet.GoogleMutant.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libraries/PuMAP_v1.7.6/EXT/translate/lang.js"></script>
```

The problem is that this scripts are getting cached the first time the application goes up, and then, instead of requesting the new scripts, the app load those scripts from the cache. That's the part I don't want.

**The reality**

Since this app is updated everyday and putted in production, we cannot ask the tester to everyday manually clear the cache of their browser. So we wanted to achieve *a way* that everytime the application get loaded by a browser, it first clean up the cache. As far as I've red, here's the configuration I'm trying to achieve this, but it's not working.

The build has this code:

```
ng build --environment=******* --prod --build-optimizer=false --output-hashing=all
```

the `index.html` tag are those:

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
```

That's the response from the network tab in Chrome:

[image]

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not use NPM to install the libraries and use the cache busting provided by the Angular CLI ?

Comment: Those libraries aren't used directly by the application, but they use others js file that function as a *kernel* between the app and the leaflet library. What do you mean by *cache bustin provided by the angular CLI* ?

Comment: `--output-hashing=all` creates hashes of your scripts that are randomly generated (well, hashed), meaning that you will never cache files from one version to another. But the issue is that it only works for scripts built through the CLI, and files added through script tags aren't cache-busted. Hence my first comment.

Comment: Try adding `no-store` to `Cache-control` (`content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"`).

Comment: The best solution for you seems to be adding the http reponse header Cache-Control: no-store in the index.html file. Do not add it as a meta tag in the html, add it as an HTTP response header. I don't know where you deploy your application, I use AWS and it is pretty simple to add this header there https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-object-metadata.html

Comment: I've now included everything in the .angular-cli.json file, added the no-store and the app is being published. Hope that those changes will help. @LeandroLima the application is published on our internal servers and the scripts are not being requested by an http call sadly.